# How to clear a table in hbase?

Tags: php, hbase

I want to empty a table in hbase... eg: `user`. Is there any command or function to empty the table without deleting it...

My table structure is :

```
$mutations = array(
                new Mutation( array(
                    'column' => 'username:1',
                    'value' =>$name
                ) ),
                new Mutation( array(
                    'column' => 'email:1',
                    'value' =>$email
                ) )
        );          
$hbase->mutateRow("user",$key,$mutations);
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There's no single command to clear Hbase table, but you can use 2 workarounds: disable, delete, create table, or scan all records and delete each.

Actually, disable, delete and create table again takes about 4 seconds.

```
// get Hbase client
$client = <Your code here>;
$t = "table_name";

$tables = $client->getTableNames();

if (in_array($t, $tables)) {
  if ($client->isTableEnabled($t))
    $client->disableTable($t);

  $client->deleteTable($t);
}

$descriptors = array(
  new ColumnDescriptor(array("name" =>  "c1", "maxVersions" => 1)),
  new ColumnDescriptor(array("name" =>  "c2", "maxVersions" => 1))
);

$client->createTable($t, $descriptors);
```

If there's not a lot of data in table - scan all rows and delete each is much faster.

```
$client = <Your code here>;
$t = "table_name";

// i don't remember, if list of column families is actually needed here
$columns = array("c1", "c2");

$scanner = $client->scannerOpen($t, "", $columns);
while ($result = $client->scannerGet($scanner)) {
  $client->deleteAllRow($t, $result[0]->row);
}
```

In this case data is not deleted physically, actually it's "marked as deleted" and stays in table until next major compact.

Comment: You could simply use 'truncate' or 'truncate_preserve' !

Answer (score 72):

If you execute this in HBase shell:

```
 > truncate 'yourTableName'
```

Then HBase will execute this operations for 'yourTableName':

```
 > disable 'yourTableName'
 > drop 'yourTableName'
 > create 'yourTableName', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'
```

Comment: 'truncate' doesn't preserve the table's permissions. However, the newer command 'truncate_preserve' does

Answer (score 5):

Another efficient option is to actually delete the table then reconstruct another one with all the same settings as the previous.

I don't know how to do this in php, but I do know how to do it in Java. The corresponding actions in php should be similar, you just need to check how the API looks like.

In Java using HBase 0.90.4:

```
// Remember the "schema" of your table
HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(yourConfiguration);
HTableDescriptor td = admin.getTableDescriptor(Bytes.toBytes("yourTableName");

// Delete your table
admin.disableTable("yourTableName");
admin.deleteTable("yourTableName");

// Recreate your talbe
admin.createTable(td);
```

Comment: Even better, there is a shell command availble for doing exactly this. And it is called truncate. Read about it here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell

Answer (score 5):

Using `hbase shell`, `truncate <table_name>` will do the task.

The snapshot of `truncate 'customer_details'` command is shown below:[image]

where `customer_details` is the table name

Answer (score 3):

truncate command in hbase shell will do the job for you:

Before truncate:
[image]

After truncate:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

HBase thrift API (which is what php is using) doesn't provide a truncate command only deleteTable and createTable functionality (what's the diff from your point of view?)

otherwise you have to scan to get all the keys and deleteAllRow for each key - which isn't a very efficient option

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of this you can use [HAdmin](https://hadmin.io). It is an UI tool for Apache HBase administration. There are "Truncate table" and even "Delete table" buttons in alter table page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using **alter** command

> `alter '<table_name>', NAME=>'column_family',TTL=><number_of_seconds>`

here **number_of_seconds** stands for duration after which data will be automatically deleted.

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps using one of these two commands:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE 1;
```

Or

```
TRUNCATE your_table;
```

Regards!

Comment: @Micku These are standard SQL statements, it is strange not work. The user you use to connect to the database, do you have permission to perform a DELETE or TRUNCATE?.